# NBA assignment of $urandom

Tags: system-verilog

Can $urandom be NBA assigned in a for loop to an unpacked array of variables?

```
module tb();

logic clk [2];
initial clk[0] = 0;
always clk[0] = #1ns !clk[0];

for (genvar i = 1; i < 2; i++)
        assign #(1ns/2) clk[i] = clk[i-1];

int tmp [2] [8];
always @ (posedge clk[0]) begin
        foreach (tmp[0][i]) begin
                /*int m;
                m = $urandom();  // SECTION 1 - using this code works (commenting out SECTION 2)
                tmp[0][i] <= m;*/
                tmp[0][i] <= $urandom(); // SECTION 2
        end
        #1ns;
        foreach (tmp[0][i]) begin
                $display("%1d", tmp[0][i]);
        end
        $finish();
end

for (genvar i = 1; i < 2; i++) begin
        always_ff @ (posedge clk[i]) begin
                tmp[i] <= tmp[i-1]; // SECTION 3 (just removing this works too)
        end
end

endmodule
```

Using Cadence tools (xrun 17.09-v002), I get all 8 of tmp[0] ints assigned the same value.

```
-2147414528
-2147414528
-2147414528
-2147414528
-2147414528
-2147414528
-2147414528
-2147414528
```

Can someone confirm whether this code is legal?

I have spoken to Cadence and been told this:
R&D’s response.

This use model of having $urandom call inside a non-blocking assignment is wrong.
The scheduling semantics of System Verilog dictates that the RHS is calculated and sampled once in the "inactive region" and then in the "NBA region" it's assigned the ALL of the elements of the foreach at the same time!

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in calling `$urandom` in a procedural loop versus serially calling `$urandom` multiple times. Your code gives the desired results in several tools, including Cadence's on EDAPlayground.com. Perhaps you are not showing is part of your problem. It always helps to show an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), like

```
module top;
  int tmp [2] [8];
  bit clk;

  initial begin
    #1 clk=1;

    #1 $display("%p",
                tmp[0]);
  end

always @ (posedge clk) begin
    foreach (tmp[,i]) begin
        tmp[0][i] <= $urandom();
    end
end

endmodule
```

Comment: 'The scheduling semantics of System Verilog dictates that the RHS is calculated and sampled once in the "inactive region"'. Is that even true? I thought the RHS would be sampled in whatever region the line containing the NBA was executed (usually the active region).

Comment: I have no idea where they are coming up with that quote.

Comment: I have a small test case showing what I believe to be a bug in Cadence’s tools. It starts with NBA assignment of $urandom. The response they gave us that an NBA assignment of $urandom is wrong. I’m just trying to figure out if they are correct. I’ll post the test case later today.